# String from dropdownlist contains < in itextshpar

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, special-characters, asp.net-mvc-5

My application is MVC5, I get a string value from a dropdownlist, the item value is <20%.

If I try to append another string with the value of the item it cuts it.

for example:

```
string itemvalue = x; /*item value from the dropdownlist*/
string totalvalue = "score" + x;
```

on debug, the total value = score <20%.  However when I print it using itextsharp HTMLWorker I only get score!

Comment: are you escaping the < sign before you emit it back to the browser?

Comment: How are you creating the string within iTextSharp? Are you creating a `Chunk`, `Phrase` or `Paragraph` manually? Are you parsing HTML using `HTMLWorker` or `XMLWorker`? Also, what version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: I am using HTMLWorker. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<` is an html tag. you can replace it with `&lt;`

```
string itemvalue = x; /*item value from the dropdownlist*/
string totalvalue = "score" + x;
totalvalue.Replace("<","&lt;");
// you can use it now! ;)
```

other things:
`>` should be `&gt;`
refer to http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: Thanks, could not resolve replace; I used HttpUtility.HtmlEncode.

Comment: It should be Replace.

Comment: yeah! i just coded from my imagination! :D
I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think using this will solve your issue

```
string itemvalue = x; /*item value from the dropdownlist*/
string totalvalue = String.Format( "score{0}",x);
```

Why not this 
remove `%` from String

```
 String.Format( "score{0}%",x);
```

#### OR

```
 String.Format( "score{0:00%}",x);
```

Comment: Thank you I think the problem is in itextsharp HTMLWorker.

Answer (score 0):

I used HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(totalvalue), worked.